# Echoing a variable in Batch is not working?

Tags: batch-file

I am currently trying to echo the text for a text based adventure game in Batch. My code looks like this:

```
...

    echo.
    echo Hello Adventurer.
    echo. 
    echo Please tell us your name:
    set /p pass =
    echo.

...

echo You will be searching for the Golden Egg %pass% . You are the des...
```

It's not working, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Try to be more specific than 'not working'. What happens when you attempt to run the script?

Comment: I do not see a single example in the help file for the `SET` command that shows a space after the variable name and before the equals symbol. Nor does it describe that usage in any way.

Comment: When I run the code, it just leaves the space where I put the variable blank. Like the code wasn't even there.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space around the `=`, i.e.

```
set /p pass=
```

(Currently your variable is actually called `%pass %`)